# Dynamic PDO parameter binding issue with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a search form where users can enter a few pieces of information to search for records in the database.  Due to the fact that some of the fields can be left blank, I am dynamically creating the WHERE clause of the query as well as dynamically binding the PDO parameters.  Everything works great if the user only fills out 1 field in the search form but if more than 1 field is used then an empty array is returned. Here is my code.

```
if(count($_POST)>0)
{   
    //Remove any key that has no value  
    $data = array_filter($_POST);

    //Define array to hold the pieces of the where clause
    $where = array();

    //loop each of the variable to build the query
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
    {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);

        //Push values to array
        array_push($where, "$key=:$key");
    }

    //Create the select query
        $query = "SELECT application_ID, 
                     student_last_name, 
                     student_first_name,
                     s.school_name,
                     DATE_FORMAT(submission_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS  submission_datetime, 
                     aps.name  
                     FROM application a
                     LEFT JOIN application_status aps ON(aps.status_ID = a.application_status_ID)
                     LEFT JOIN schools s ON(s.school_ID = a.school_choice)";
    //As long as criteria was selected in the search form then add the where clause to the query with user's search criteria
    if(!empty($where))
    {       
        $query .= "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where);
    }

    //Add ORDER BY clause to the query
    $query .= " ORDER BY application_ID";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    //loop each of the variables to bind parameters
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $stmt->bindparam(':'.$key, $value);
        }
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


}
```

When I echo the query everything looks fine and even returns results when run from PHPMyAdmin. Here is the query.

```
SELECT application_ID, 
       student_last_name, 
       student_first_name, 
       s.school_name, 
       DATE_FORMAT(submission_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS submission_datetime,
       aps.name 
       FROM application a 
       LEFT JOIN application_status aps ON(aps.status_ID = a.application_status_ID)
       LEFT JOIN schools s ON(s.school_ID = a.school_choice)
       WHERE school_choice=:school_choice AND status_ID=:status_ID 
       ORDER BY application_ID ASC
```

When I print_r I get an empty array.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through an array to bind values to the PDO statement you should use bindValue instead of bindParam.

When you say `$stmt->bindparam(':'.$key, $value)`, the query will use the value of the variable `$value` as it is at the time of the query execution. Value of `$value` will be the last element of the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with prepared statements. And in fact, this function will not work if you don't have a `mysql_connect()` initialized, which you don't.

That must be why it all is failing, your calls to `mysql_real_escape_string()` are returning `FALSE` for everything.

Also, what makes you think array keys coming from `$_POST` are safe to be used in your SQL query? You are taking a serious risk of SQL injection here, don't ever do that.