# PDO update same value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a problem with my php and PDO, 
I trying to make a update query with a dynamic number of column updated, 
I have a form and when I set more than one value, the query run and in my DB I get all the value set in the form set at the last value.

```
public static function modifierCours($cours){
    echo '<pre>';
    BaseDeDonnee::init();
    $bind=array();
    $donne=$cours->toArray();
    $sql= 'update cours set ';
    foreach ($donne as $key=>$value){
        $key= str_replace(" ", "", $key);
        if (!strstr($key,"idcours") && !empty($value)) {
            $sql .= $key . "=:" . $key . ' , ';
            $bind[$key]=$value;
        }
    }
    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -2);
    $sql.= " where idcours =".$cours->idcours;
    $requete = BaseDeDonnee::$connection->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($bind as $key=>$value){
        $key=":".$key;
        if (strstr($key,"matiere") && !strstr($key,"idcours")){
            $requete->bindParam($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        else if (!strstr($key,"matiere") && !strstr($key,"idcours")){
            $requete->bindParam($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }
    echo $sql;
    $requete->debugDumpParams();
    //var_dump(":type");
    //var_dump($requete);
    $requete->execute();

}
```

```
> SQL: [87] update cours set titre=:titre , description=:description , type=:type  where idcours =5
Params:  3
Key: Name: [6] :titre
paramno=-1
name=[6] ":titre"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [12] :description
paramno=-1
name=[12] ":description"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [5] :type
paramno=-1
name=[5] ":type"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

is the pdo debug

please help me, I found nothing on internet.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($bind);` after the first `foreach`?

Comment: ```array(3) {
  ["titre"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["description"]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "Vidéo"
}``` like this?

Comment: And you're saying that "Vidéo" is being saved to all three columns?

Comment: exactly ! all the three columns .

Comment: Use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`.  When you use `bindParam()`, you are tying the placeholder to the actual _variable_, not the _value_ of the variable at the time of binding.  Since you are looping and updating `$value` each time through the loop, you are changing what is connected to the placeholder.  I'm going to see if I can find a good dupe for this.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019826/php-generate-dynamic-pdo-insert) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475703/dynamic-pdo-parameter-binding-issue-with-where-clause), there are also others.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and the explication, I have never heard about bindValue!